# Concatenation script url

Tags: vb.net

I have vb.net code in which file is opening from url i want to concatenate the selected date from dropdownlist in the file url date
My code is bleow

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", "window.open('/Reports/Daily Production and Stock Report (Crescent Ujala)/Daily Production and Stock Report (Crescent Ujala) 2011.11.01.xls');", True)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings?

Comment: I want to replace the date in url with date slected from dropdownlist

Comment: Dim fname As String fname = DD1.SelectedValue
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", "window.open('/Reports/Daily Production and Stock Report (Crescent Ujala)/Daily Production and Stock Report (Crescent Ujala) 2011.11.01.xls');", True)  i want to replace fname with date in url

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate strings?

Comment: I knew but its not working with & sign u plz tell me how to replace 2011.11.01 with fname

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please any one help me its so urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"some string" & someDateTime.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") & "some other string"
```